# MSFT Contoso University Tutorial on EF and MVC Inheriting from Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In this tutorial: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application theres a part where the code is this:

```
public class SchoolInitialzier : System.Data.Entity, 
                    DropCreateDatabaseModelChanges<SchoolContext>
```

It gives me these errors:

`System.Data.Entity is a namespace but is used like a type.
The type or namespace name DropCreateDatabaseModelChanges could not be found`

What does it mean when you inherit something that way?  Is it even correct?  Why is MSFT tutorial telling me to do it?  What  is the proper way to do what it is  trying to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: That should be `System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseModelChanges<SchoolContext>`. You're using a `,` comma.

Comment: jeez, thanks okay. post answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo with the `,` comma

```
System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseModelChanges<SchoolContext>
```

If you were implementing two interfaces then you would have a comma

```
public class Foo : IIdentity, IKnowsKungFoo
```